# Converting array of integers/decimal points to a single number

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if there is a way to take an array of integers (and possibly decimal points) and convert them into a single number (an `int` or a `double`)? For example, if I had the array {4, 1, ., 9}, is it possible to convert it into a `double`, 41.9? I am implementing a way to do it by iteration and *10 to various powers, but I'm not sure if it will work out because of rounding errors and such (will it calculate i.e., 9 * (10^-1) correctly all the time?).

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  No language or computer can represent 0.9 exactly using the native floating-point types, like `float` or `double`.  So please don't call this "Java's rounding errors".  These are errors that are endemic to almost every computer.  Java has a `BigDecimal` class that can be used if you need exact amounts with decimal fractions.

Comment: @ajb: I think you need to be more specific: no *binary* computer that uses the *popular* floating-point representation can store `0.9` exactly. You can however store it exactly using fractions, or by using a radix of 10 (this is the case for a `decimal`),...

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, I could have been a bit more precise.  But I think what you mean by "popular" is what I mean by "native", since the "popular" types are generally the ones built-in to the hardware.  And I haven't seen a computer that dealt with decimal floating-point types natively since some of those old Burroughs beasts in the 1970s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a quick and dirty solution is to convert your array of integers and points (in which case you probably have a char array like so: `{'4','1','.','9'}`) into a string, `"41.9"` and then use the Double.parseDouble(s) to parse your string to a double. It wont be fast, though.

Comment: Is there a way to convert part of an array (so from a specified index to another) into a string? Or is the only way to make another array that contains only the part that I want to convert?

Comment: You can use substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) to specify beginning and end of the string you want to include

Comment: Isn't a problem with this approach what to do if you have for instance two points, say `{4,1,0.9,0.7}`?

Comment: Yeah, that would result in a NumberFormatException. Obviously, you have to keep the format in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the possible values in the array are very limited (for instance `0` to `9`) and the number of elements is not that large.

The following algorithm works does this:

```
long l = 0x00;
int[] array = {5,2,3,6,7,8};
int radix = 9;
for(int i = 0x00; i < array.length; i++) {
    l *= radix;
    l += array[i];
}
return l;
```

Where radix is the maximum value `+1`.

Even then however, a long has a maximum value of `2^63-1` or `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`. That means that if the number of possible values per item is 10, you can only store 17 items.

---

A `double` won't solve the problem. Since `double`s use floating point semantics, they can only store approx. 12 decimals correctly. If you store more in a double, information will get lost eventually. What happens to the least significant values depends on the larger values (since half of the time a `0` will be generates as least significant bit, and `1` in the other case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not at all worried about the said limitations, so I think I am good for now. :)